# How to divide two aggregate columns in a pandas groupby object?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm working with a dataset that involves referral information, and the total amount paid out for each promo that's being run. I'm able to get the count of total purchases within each promo, and the sum of the amount paid out for each promo, but I'm getting stuck on being able to divide the two aggregate columns to obtain the average amount paid out to obtain a new purchase. here is a subset of what the data looks like:

```
bucket  receiver_quote  total_paid
0   168hr   0   NaN
1   168hr   0   NaN
2   168hr   1   100.0
3   168hr   1   50.0
4   168hr   1   100.0
5   48hr    1   75.0
6   48hr    0   NaN
7   48hr    0   NaN
8   48hr    0   NaN
9   48hr    0   NaN
```

Right now, I'm able to obtain this table:

```
df.groupby('bucket').agg({'receiver_policy':'sum', 'total_paid': 'sum})
```

Result:

| bucket | receiver_policy | total_paid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0hr | 45 | 11375.0 |
| 168hr | 27 | 6725.0 |
| 48hr | 31 | 7200.0 |
| off | 31 | 4200.0 |

I'd like to be able to divide the total_paid by receiver_policy, to obtain the average amount spent per policy, like this:

| bucket | receiver_policy | total_paid | avg_paid_per_policy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0hr | 45 | 11375.0 | 252.78 |
| 168hr | 27 | 6725.0 | 249.07 |
| 48hr | 31 | 7200.0 | 232.26 |
| off | 31 | 4200.0 | 135.48 |

But I'm discovering that I can't divide two aggregate functions when creating the groupby object, like this.

```
  df.groupby('bucket').agg({'receiver_policy':'sum', 'total_paid': 'sum',
                              'avg_paid_per_policy': np.sum/np.size})
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'function' and 'function'

I'm sure there's something obvious I'm missing, anyone have any tips? Thank you!

Comment: If you are trying to find the average why not just use mean `df.groupby('bucket').agg({'receiver_policy':'sum', 'total_paid': ['sum', 'mean']})`?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified - the receiver_policy column has a lot of NANs in it because not everyone bought a policy. When I called the mean function it didn't return the same value that I would want if I were to divide the two columns.

Comment: Can you update the question with sample data that is more representative or your actual data and an expected output for the sample data?

Comment: I added a header of the data and the table I would like to come up with.

Comment: Great, one clarification.  For the sample data you provided, are you expecting the average to be `[83.33, 75]` or `[50, 15]`? For the first output just do what was I mentioned above. For the second (which is based on the size and includes nan in the count) then do `df.fillna(0).groupby('bucket').agg({'receiver_quote':'sum', 'total_paid': ['sum', 'mean']})`

Answer (score 0):

- your sample data and sample code do not match columns.   Have adapted to this
- simple use of `groupby().apply()` returning a series of all the calculations you want for the group

```
df = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        """bucket  receiver_quote  total_paid
0   168hr   0   NaN
1   168hr   0   NaN
2   168hr   1   100.0
3   168hr   1   50.0
4   168hr   1   100.0
5   48hr    1   75.0
6   48hr    0   NaN
7   48hr    0   NaN
8   48hr    0   NaN
9   48hr    0   NaN"""
    ),
    sep="\s+",
)

df.groupby("bucket").agg({"receiver_quote": "sum", "total_paid": "sum"})

df.groupby("bucket").apply(
    lambda d: pd.Series(
        {
            "receiver_quote": d["receiver_quote"].sum(),
            "total_paid": d["total_paid"].sum(),
            "avg_paid_per_policy":d["total_paid"].sum() / d["receiver_quote"].sum()
        }
    )
)
```

| bucket | receiver_quote | total_paid | avg_paid_per_policy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 168hr | 3 | 250 | 83.3333 |
| 48hr | 1 | 75 | 75 |

Comment: Oof, sorry, I grabbed the wrong column when creating the header data. I will take a look at this - thank you so much!